# http chunked реализация на с#

Tags: c#, http

Подскажите где почитать на русском. Не могу пока англоязычную документацию переваривать.

Не совсем понимаю даже основы. Если мы хотим залить файл на сервер. Мы шлем post запрос с multipart|form датой и заголовком Range. Что указывать в заголовке не совсем понял. Особенно когда указывается несколько Range. Может ли сервер запрашивать в ответе какой-нибудь Range...

Вообще, тыкните, где почитать, ну или распишите для нуба, если не лень)